# Can't save dataset in CSV file using Python

Tags: python, csv, save, dataset

I have a dataset in a CSV file. I want to save some columns of this csv file and the sentiment score of its row, in a new CSV file. Unfortunately, when i try to do that, the only output is on the console, and the new file include nothing. Do anybody know, why this happens?

```
with  open('semevalSenti80.csv', 'wb' ) as fileOutput:
    writer = csv.writer(fileOutput)
    inpTweets = csv.reader(open('semeval80.csv', 'rb'), delimiter='"', quotechar='|')
    stopWords = getStopWordList('stopwords.txt')
    featureList = []
    tweetsTrain = []

    for row in inpTweets:
        if len(row) != 0:
            score = 0
            tweet = row[1]
            processedTweet = processTweet(tweet)
            featureVector = getFeatureVector(processedTweet, stopWords)
            featureList.extend(featureVector)
            for ft in featureVector:
                score = score + get_scores("SentiWordNet_3.0.0_20130122.txt", ft)
                print score, row
                writer.writerow([row[1], score])
                if score > 0:
                    tweetsTrain.append((featureVector, "positive"))
                elif score < 0:
                    tweetsTrain.append((featureVector, "negative"))
                else:
                    tweetsTrain.append((featureVector, "neutral"))
```

Comment: You are opening `fileIntro.csv` twice.

Comment: First you should no catch everything and just do a `continue`. Obviously your code always throws an exception. Place a breakpoint after `except`, or print out the error message.

Comment: @toti08 i delete the `open('fileIntro.csv', 'r') as fileIntro,` but it still happens

Comment: @Mathias is this has to with the error or only to a good methodology?

Comment: @Mathias This code does not always throws an exception, because it prints in console tweets and their scores, but it does not save them in csv

Comment: It may print something BUT then an exception happen before you're able to write something into the file. Remove the try/except block, then you get a reasonable traceback/errormsg.

Comment: @Mathias i removed the try /except block and the error message that i got was the fallowin `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/project/senti.py", line 144, in <module>
    tweet = row[1]
IndexError: list index out of range` how can i solve that. my input csv is a file with 3 columns and the first row is their headers

Comment: You can try maybe to add a `if len(row) != 0` so that you only process lines with data on it.

Comment: @toti08 i add `if len(row) != 0`, i got rid of the IndexError, but there is still nothing in my new csv

Comment: You can then print the content of each line to see how each line is made, this should give you some indication on the error.

Comment: @toti08 i print a copy of each line, and this work perfectly. The only problem is that i still not writting these results in csv

Comment: @toti08 ,of course, i did it

Comment: Indentation is a major concern in Python, and current code **cannot** be indented as shown on post. Please ensure your are displaying  code here with the same indentation than in your real code. An incorrect indentation could be the cause of your problem.

Comment: @SergeBallesta , yes is the same as in my code now

Comment: Evgenia, maybe you are looking at another csv file. Run `tree` in your project directory to show all project resources used in source code.

Comment: Add full source of senti.py if you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just split your larger task into simpler parts. The last two lines are using the smaller parts to compose a processing pipeline to do your larger task. There is room for improvements, but this will get you the idea.

```
import csv

stopWords = getStopWordList('stopwords.txt')

def get_tweets(csv_file):
    "return list of tweet items"
    with open(csv_file, 'rb') as f:
        tweets = csv.reader(f, delimiter='"', quotechar='|')
        return tweets

def process_score(tweet):
    "compute score for given tweet text"
    score = 0
    processedTweet = processTweet(tweet)
    featureVector = getFeatureVector(processedTweet, stopWords)
    for feature in featureVector:
        score = score + get_scores("SentiWordNet_3.0.0_20130122.txt", feature)                

    return score

def save_scores(csv_file, tweet_scores):
    "save given iterable to csv file"
    with open(csv_file, 'wb' ) as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(tweet_scores)


tweet_scores = [(tweet[1],process_score(tweet[1])) for tweet in get_tweets('semeval80.csv')]
save_scores('semevalSenti80.csv', tweet_scores)
```